# How to pass list/array of env variables to ENV in GO

Tags: go

I have to execute a shell script using golang, along with it I have to pass env variables as well (unknown number of variables).

```
    cmd_string := "echo $TOKEN && echo $USER_NAME"
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd_string)

    cmd_variables :=["USER_NAME=John", "TOKEN=1234", "BOOLEAN=true"]

    for _, vars := range cmd_variables {
        cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), vars)
    }
```

but it's only appending last variable in array
How to append all variables in env? any other better approad

Comment: Have you tried with [os.Setenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for _, vars := range cmd_variables {
        cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), vars)
}
```

Should be

```
cmd.Env = os.Environ()
for _, vars := range cmd_variables {
        cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, vars)
}
```

In order that each append call really append to `cmd.Env`

Comment: This is actually wrong. The moment `cmd.Env` becomes non-nil, as it does here, the child process will not inherit the parent process' environment. The correct way is a one-liner: `cmd.Env = append(os.Environ, cmd_variables...)`

Comment: I agree that the one liner `cmd.Env = append(os.Environ, cmd_variables...)` will also work, but It seems equivalent to what my answer does. So I don't really understand why you say that it's actually wrong ?

Comment: The OP's intent was only to ADD new env vars. Your solution adds new env vars, but also loses all the existing ones. This program demonstrates: https://play.golang.com/p/1qD1AXqE_yC

Comment: I'm not sure it does because the first line of the solution is to initialize cmd.Env with os.Environ(). So this copies the existing env variables, and then the loop adds the new ones.

Comment: omg. It was staring me right in the face. idk how I completely missed the first line. You are right!